# Numerate Markers in Angular 2+

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, marker

Hi good day i try numerate the markers i generate but nothing happend.

I use this:

```html
<sebm-google-map [latitude]="-34.599427" [longitude]="-58.381031" [zoom]="12">
        <div *ngFor="let location of selectedLocations; let i = index">
            <sebm-google-map-marker [label]="i" [latitude]="location.map.latitude" [longitude]="location.map.longitude">
                <sebm-google-map-info-window>
                  <strong>{{location.name}}</strong>
                  <p>{{location.map.address}}</p>
                </sebm-google-map-info-window>
            </sebm-google-map-marker>
        </div>
    </sebm-google-map>
```

Somebody know how do that with angular 2+ Map?

thanks in advance.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I solved this in this way:

```js
<agm-map [latitude]="touristZone.map.latitude" [longitude]="touristZone.map.longitude" [zoom]="12">
            <div *ngFor="let location of selectedTouristZones; let j = index">
              <agm-marker [iconUrl]="icono + j + ext" [latitude]="location.map.latitude" [longitude]="location.map.longitude">
                <agm-info-window>
                  <strong>{{location.name}}</strong>
                  <p>{{location.map.address}}</p>
                </agm-info-window>
              </agm-marker>
            </div>
          </agm-map>
```

I create a pin img with the numbers in this.

In the ts this is the variable:

```js
  icono = 'app/assets/images/map/markers/pin';
  ext = '.png';
```

Regards